# Module and Ring such that tensor of modules is isomorphic to the module, given certain limitations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

> I'm trying to find any other examples of when a module $M$ over a ring
>   $R$ is such that
>
> $$ M \otimes_R M \cong M $$
>
> with the limitations that $M \not \cong S^{-1}R$ and $M \not \cong R/I$ for any ideal $I$ or localization $S$.

I've been trying to work with finite modules and think about them as direct sums of cyclic groups, especially idempotents, to help inform this, but I'm having trouble constructing an actual isomorphism. In particular, can $(0,1)\otimes (1,0)$ ever be the same element as $(1,0)\otimes (0,1)$?

Any hints?

Thanks!!

Comment: I do not they exist at least when $R$ is Noetherian and $M$ finitely generated, other than $R/I$.

Comment: I think you're ring about the finitely generated ones. Right now I'm trying to figure out though $\mathbb{Z}[x]\otimes_\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{Z}[x]$.... will report back

Comment: $\mathbb Z[x]$ is a countably generated free $\mathbb Z$-module and any countably generated $R$-module is going to be an example of what you're looking for.

Comment: $M$ can also be a localization of a quotient!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the polynomial ring in infinitely many variables $M = R[x_1,...]$.
$$M\otimes_RM = R[x_1,x_2,...]\otimes_RR[y_1,y_2,...] = R[x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...] \simeq M$$

Comment: In fact it suffices to take the polynomial ring in a single variable, as Guest notes in the comments.

Comment: That's true. I guess my examples works also in the category of $R$-algebras, but for modules it is overkill.